# Why is object creation fast in Scala?

Tags: scala

From [this comparison](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking?ts=1237772203&updated=Benchmarking) of serialization libraries on the JVM, it looks like it is faster to create an object in Scala than in Java. The difference is in nanoseconds, though.

Is there any real reason why it would take less time to create an object in Scala, or the graph just reflects improper benchmarking or some other sort of imprecision?

Comment: Does that benchmark test all the various flavors of the different garbage collectors?

Comment: This question is misleading (and while interesting, I am down-voting for the following reasons). **Different serialization techniques/libraries are used.** It is flaw to take this to mean object creation is *faster* in Scala than Java (or environment X). To use that link to argue this point would require a very close inspection of *just* the relevant factors -- possible bytcode inspection and **exact object graph serialized**. As for why Scala object creation is "cheap" and short-lived objects are "cheap"? It's because of the JVM optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

40 nanosecond difference in object creation time is background noise in a Intel Core i7 920.

Assuming the numbers are an average over several runs, 40 nanoseconds is just 0.04 microseconds.  Assuming on Windows 7 64-bit that the High Performance clock was functioning correctly, you're probably looking at hiccups in windows, the phase of the moon, statistical error, measuring program error, memory allocation implementation speeds, or something else entirely.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense given how consistent the timings are across many different tests.  14 of the 23 timings are between 168 and 176!

Comment: It means it was nigh instantaneous.  Infact, the other ones that deviate from the "Instant" category could actually have taken the same amount of time.  We're talking 168 nanoseconds here. Absent other load, and absent actual testing methodology, there's too many variables.  Assuming modern ram, you're talking roughly 7-12 nanoseconds spent on the first word thrown into ram.  That you're seeing so many fall within such a narrow field *could* indicate that it represents the "fastest" that machine can process memory access/creation.

Comment: A *better* test would be to see how long it takes each language to create one million, or billion, or trillion objects (depending on object composition, which i couldn't find on that site, which dictates how much memory access (the real speed killer) must be done).  That way you're pushing yourself above the "minimum measurement" barrier.  Of course..then you might be influenced by windows doing something in the background, or some daemon on linux.  To *really* get down to it, you'd have to be running on a real time OS, and *even then* you're going to get bit by randomness in your measurements

Comment: Ergo, There is inherient in any computer system you are attempting to measure, even a Real time OS like VxWorks, a certain amount of "Noise".  Background tasks that will swipe CPU time from you, paging you in and out.  The "best" way I've found to account for this is to run each test 10-100 times, and average the results..

Comment: @Caladain - You have looked at the source code of the test and you know that it isn't creating a huge number of objects?  And that it's not averaging multiple runs?

Comment: @Rex - Nope, just answering the base question.  I poked about, but wasn't going to go digging through source code to definitively say "yep, he messed up".  When presenting results, that should be stated in your testing methodology.  After all, he posted the machine he used.  But, lets assume he is creating a million objects, taking the total amount of time, and dividing to figure out how long each object took.  This is inaccurate (trying to figure each object creation time) as you'll be looking at memory access times/paging more than object creation.  40 nanoseconds is faster than the........

Comment: ........Clock on that i7, on *windows*.  Any "resolution" then isn't a hardware clock, but software, which means it's subject to the vagueness of being paged/the kernel, which reduces it's accuracy and reliability.  What's more, the testing was done on windows, which has a maximum resolution, under most circumstances when using the high-performance clock on a system that supports it, of a microsecond.  *Not* nanosecond.  And it's vanilla *Windows 7*.  Not Vxworks or some other Real Time OS.  OP was concerned about 40 nanoseconds.  It's irrelevant to the language comparison, noise.

Comment: @Caladain - Hardware clocks don't save you from variable timing based on cache misses and whatnot.  The data shows pretty clearly that despite all your huffing, they can get timings with a reproducibility of about 8 ns.  How _meaningful_ this will be in a dramatically different usage case is open to question, but it's not "noise" or "hiccups".

Comment: They don't save you from variable timing, but they will accurately indicate how long it took *with* those variables included.  Software clocks have no such promise.  And, given that the highest resolution clock on a i7-930 is 1 microsecond, the only way to get nanosecond resolution would be a software clock (in essence, doing a loop for a 100 times every program cycle), which is, by it's very nature, not reliable.  All that will measure is how many program cycles you experienced, not how long it took, or wallclock time.  It'll give you a good approximation though :-)

Comment: @Caladain - With appropriate methodology it's reliable to at least 8 ns measured (given whatever they did in this benchmark).

Answer (score 1):

Scala creates more small objects automatically.  This makes object creation faster *on average* but the serialization size larger.

Comment: do you have any details/link to learn more about the "Scala creating smaller objects than Java"? and why would not Java create them as small as Scala does?

Answer (score 0):

Update on this older post:

The page has moved,

https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki

Scala is not listed now. Searching the group did not explain why?

Old post, but arguments continued,

[Scala is faster than Java until...](http://www.eishay.com/2008/11/scala-is-faster-then-java-until-you-hit.html)

I *think* the Rex Kerr post is referring to the way Scala collection classes save their elements individually. I don't have benchmarks to hand, but this is not a little (hard to prove and unprofitably) faster, I've benchmarked as repeatedly faster. Presumably, the Scala coders know this.

See the code for readObject/writeObject methods in the Scala collection ImmutableList here,

[Code page for Immutable List](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1)

loop, loop...

A quick look at the benchmark code,

[benchmark code for Scala](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/blob/master/tpc/src/serializers/Scala.scala)

shows use of JavaConversions._ which, in the ongoing flux of development, and bearing the above in mind, may have given/give Scala a *slight* advantage.